# Java standalone application in n systems without manual installation?

Tags: java, swing, deployment, installation, desktop-application

I've done a java application for a hospital. The application is an ERP software. The application is to be installed in around n systems. 
But installing the same application in all these systems is a bit difficult and it requires a lot of time.

Even if that has been done, in the future, if the application requires even a little modification, then again the modified application should be replaced in all those systems in the hospital. I'm using mysql as my database, which i've placed within the main hospital server from where all other systems access it through the network.

Through RMI method we can access it somehow, but RMI is a bit too slow.

Can anyone tell me some solutions or suggestion to achieve a solution for this problem?

In the case of java web application we can deploy the application war file within a main server and all the systems within a LAN or any other network can get the application through the browser. Is there any similar solution in the case for my Desktop Java Swing application which is a exe, jar based app.

How to get a Java Deskop Swing application in an around 200 systems without manual installation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check java webstart? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html

Comment: The people on ServerFault probably have better advice for you than most of the people reading this here.

Comment: I agree with Alexei, Webstart is the intended technology for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java Web Start is the best solution. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html

Comment: See also the [Java Web Start tag. Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) for handy links.

Comment: Java Web Start seems to be good. but sir Is AJAX-SWING better than Java Web Start

Answer (score 3):

Using Java Web Start is one the way to solve your problem. Try [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html) to learn Java Web Start.